# Detecting no file selected in input file control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I need to choose image to display it on screen from select control, if there is no desired image I want to choose it from disk and put this option into select control and select it automatically. The problem scenario is if I select an "add" option and cancel file dialog then "add" option will stay selected, so file dialog won't show up if I chose that option again. In this case I want to automatically select my hidden placeholder option, but I dunno how to detect that no file was selected. Is there a propper way how can I detect it and deal with it?

I have attached my html controls and how I work with their events.

```
$("#file_upload").change(function() {
    const file = $("#file_upload")[0].files[0];
    var text = file.name.slice(0, -4);
    fill_img_options(text);
});



var fill_img_options = function(text) {
    $("#img_selector").append(`<option value='${text}'>${text}</option>`);
    $("#img_selector").val(text).change();
};


$("#img_selector").change(function () {
    const selectedName = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("name");
    if (selectedName === "add") {
        $("#file_upload").click();
        return;
    }
});


<div class="form-inline">
      @*hidden element for uploading image*@
      <input type="file" id="file_upload" accept=".jpg" style="position: fixed; top: -100em">
      <label for="img_selector">Choose img:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="img_selector">
           <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;" name="placeholder">Image</option>
           <option name="add">Add...</option>
       </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: The issue appears to be a typo, trailing `)` following closing `}` at `var fill_img_options = function(text) {}` https://plnkr.co/edit/rgELOsfQqwDOi8spw1nY?p=preview?

Comment: @guest271314 oh, thx for pointing, but there is no typo in my source code, made mistake when i was editing my question.

Comment: Well `$("#file_upload")[0].files` probably won’t contain much, if no file was selected ...

Comment: @CBroe I guess so, but I'm not sure that change event should be triggered in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `.change()` call within `fill_img_options` function, call `$(this).val("")` within `change` event of `<select>` element, within `change` event of `<input type="file">` element check if `file` exists within `if` condition, if true pass file name to `fill_img_options()`, set `<input type="file">` `.value` to an empty string

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <!-- @*hidden element for uploading image*@ -->
    <input type="file" id="file_upload" accept=".jpg" style="position: fixed; top: -100em" />
    <label for="img_selector">Choose img:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="img_selector">
      <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display:none;" name="placeholder">Image</option>
      <option name="add">Add...</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#file_upload").change(function() {

      const file = $("#file_upload")[0].files[0];
      // check if file is selected
      if (file) {
        var text = file.name.slice(0, -4);
        fill_img_options(text);
      }
      $("#file_upload")[0].value = "";
    });



    var fill_img_options = function(text) {
      $("#img_selector").append(`<option value='${text}'>${text}</option>`);
      // remove `.change()` to prevent recursive dispatch of `change` event
      $("#img_selector").val(text);
    };


    $("#img_selector").change(function() {
      const selectedName = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("name");
      if (selectedName === "add") {
        $("#file_upload").click();
        // set value attribute to empty string
        $(this).val("");
        return;
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```